# Android Kotlin - Problema con Hilt y Retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, mvvm, dagger

Estoy migrando una aplicación Android para usar Hilt y clean arquitecture, y me he quedado atascado en los primeros pasos sin entender el motivo.
Las dos primeras activities de la aplicación son una de login, que a su vez tiene un link a una de registro para darse de alta.
He creado el modulo de retrofit y la API para implementar las llamadas al backend. Tambien he creado la viewModel para la activity login y todo funciona perfectamente. Pero al replicar lo mismo exactamente en la activity de registro, la aplicación se cae. He ido haciendo pruebas y esta actividad no llega ni siquiera a llamar al módulo de retrofit, da el fallo en el momento que inyecto la API con Hilt.

Esta es mi actividad de login:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity () {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<LoginViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val credenciales = RegistroRequestDto(
                    user = binding.editTextUser.text.toString(),
                    password = binding.editTextPassword.text.toString()
                )

                val llamadaAPI = viewModel.appLogin(credenciales)
                if (llamadaAPI.coderror != 0)
                    binding.errormessage.text = llamadaAPI.mensaje
                else {
                    viewModel.saveData(llamadaAPI)
//                    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
        }

        binding.registro.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, Registro::class.java))
        }
    }
```

Con su viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: DataStoreRepository,
    private val API: BackEndService
) : ViewModel() {
    fun saveData(datos: UsuarioResponseDto) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.putStringDataStore(TOKEN, datos.token)
            repository.putStringDataStore(NOMBRE, datos.nombre)
            repository.putStringDataStore(NICK, datos.nick)
            repository.putIntDataStore(CODUSUARIO, datos.codusuario)
        }
    }

    suspend fun appLogin(credenciales: RegistroRequestDto) : UsuarioResponseDto{
        val response = API.login(credenciales)
        return response
    }

}
```

Esto de arriba funciona sin problema. La función adicional que no tiene que ver con Retrofit es para almacenar los datos del usuario en DataStore, que tambien funciona bien.

Esta es mi actividad registro:

```
class Registro : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityRegistroBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<RegistroViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityRegistroBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val credenciales = RegistroRequestDto(
                    user = binding.editTextUser.text.toString(),
                    password = binding.editTextPassword.text.toString()
                )
                val llamadaAPI = viewModel.registro(credenciales)
                if (llamadaAPI.code != 0)
                    binding.imageExitoONo.setImageResource(R.drawable.cruzroja)
                else
                    binding.imageExitoONo.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkverde)
                binding.imageExitoONo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.un.text = llamadaAPI.message

            }
        }

        binding.imageFlechaIzq.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Y su viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RegistroViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val API: BackEndService
) : ViewModel() {

    suspend fun registro(credenciales: RegistroRequestDto) : SimpleResponseDto{
        val response = API.requestRegistro(credenciales)
        return response
    }
}
```

Tal y como lo ejecuto, falla en cuento llamo a la funcion registro. Si comento la inyeccion de dependencias y fuerzo a response a devolver cualquier valor (con la inyeccion comentada), funciona.

Una cosa que me resulta curiosa y creo que estara relacionada, es que Android Studio en la funcion registro del viewModel Registro me da un warning de que la palabra suspend es redundante y me sugiere eliminarla, cuando no lo es al ser llamada desde una subrutina. Por supuesto, ese warning no me lo da en la funcion del viewModel login que funciona correctamente. Pero pese a tener una idea de que ese warning me esta dando una pista del problema, llevo varios dias y sigo sin ver que hay diferente entre la actividad que funciona y la que no.

Answer (score 0):

Me autocontesto. He encontrado la respuesta casi por error.
Error de novato creer que la etiqueta Hilt @AndroidEntryPoint marcaba la primera actividad de la aplicación, cuando debe marcar cada actividad que va a usar inyeccion de dependencias.

Ha sido añadir @AndroidEntryPoint a la clase Registro y todo ha funcionado sin tocar nada mas.

PD: ¿No debería el compilador advertir que estas intentando usar Hilt en una clase que no está preparada para ello?

Comment: Con el [Componente de Navegación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/migrate?hl=es-419) tú puedes tener una sola Activity en tu aplicación,  y hacer que todos los demás puntos sean fragmentos. Así, tanto Login como Registro pueden ser fragmentos de tu MainActivity por ejemplo. Dicho eso, aún no estás implementando Clean Architecture en este código.